How can I use the TIMESTAMP Data Type in GridDB with Python?
I'm building a Python app that keeps encrypted credit card data in GridDB. I want to use the TIMESTAMP data type to store the credit card expiration date instead of a STRING. But I'm running into problems when I try to use TIMESTAMP for the expiration date. My code works fine with the expiration date as a STRING, but it doesn't when I switch to TIMESTAMP.
I changed the column definition for 'expirationDate' to use 'griddb.Type.TIMESTAMP' instead of 'griddb.Type.STRING'. I also tried to turn the expiration date into a Python 'datetime' object before putting it into the GridDB container. I thought the data would be stored without any issues and that I'd be able to query it. But I keep getting errors about the data type, and I'm not sure how to format or handle the 'TIMESTAMP' data in this situation.
Below is my code:
import datetime

# Attempt to store expirationDate as a TIMESTAMP
expirationDate = datetime.datetime(2028, 12, 1)
container = griddb.ContainerInfo("CreditCard",
                                 [["id", griddb.Type.INTEGER],
                                  ["cardNumber", griddb.Type.BLOB],
                                  ["expirationDate", griddb.Type.TIMESTAMP],
                                  ["ownerName", griddb.Type.STRING]],
                                 griddb.ContainerType.COLLECTION, True)
container.put([cardId, encryptedCardNumber, expirationDate, ownerName])

